# SSR LED light on even when ESP8266 pin is off

Tags: solid-state-relay, esp8266

I'm powering a heater with an SSR and esp8266 nodemcu module. I've found out that I need a higher voltage to effectively trigger it than what the nodemcu can put out on a digital pin (from previous post [SSR ticking when controlling heater](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283223/ssr-ticking-when-controlling-heater)).

I have added a transister and diode combo into my network (based on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/220504/137437) which allows the 3.3v from the esp8266 to trigger 5v:
[image]

This works but when the digital output from the nodemcu is off, an LED on the the SSR still maintains a very slight glow.

If I power the nodemcu from a **different** wall wart that is plugged into an **external** wall socket (see diagram below) the led on the SSR is off when the digital output is off. 
[image]

Is there some feedback or something that is making the SSR Led be on when there is no power to the P1 pin? I have tried testing the voltage across the SSR low voltage input but only have a rudimentary voltage tester and when I try it doesn't read anything and the led goes off.. Or is my wall wart used in the first diagram just dodgy?

Comment: Are you using an SSR or a Relay....the schematic above indicates a relay.

Comment: An SSR, not a RLY1 as shown in above schematic.. It is a Fotek SSR (SSR-50DA http://akizukidenshi.com/download/ds/fotek/fotek_ssr.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two solutions might help you.

1. Add a 10k resistor from the Port pin to ground.
2. Add a 1k resistor directly across the SSR low voltage input pins.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide any further information on exactly what the effect of each of these would be?

Comment: 1 - reduce potential for Q1 to turn on under reset or leakage from MCU   2 - recue sensitivity of opto to small currents

Comment: OK so I tested both. Adding a 10k resistor from Port pin to ground (which is like a pull down resistor I think) didn't do anything in my case. But adding a 1K resistor across SSR low voltage pins did. This means it is essentially in parallel with the diode. Is that OK, or does it negate having a diode there? Also, does this indicate that the transistor is leaking a tiny bit of voltage and could be faulty?

Comment: Glad you fixed the problem. There are always leakage currents to consider and in this case I think you have in addition a very sensitive (high gain) optocoupler. I'd imagine the solution will be fine.